# not enter in controller when using script of create input file for upload

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i need to use dynamic upload form .

i used this script for add input file in asp mvc :

```
   <button type="button" onclick="adduploadfile()" class="btn btn-success">افزودن فایل</button>
```

*

```
    function adduploadfile() {
    $("<input>").attr('type', 'file').attr('name', 'NewsFilePath').attr('class', 'form-control NewsFilePathUpload')
    .appendTo('.insertfileuploads');
}
```

and use this code for upload image :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.NewsFilePathUpload').change(function () {
    $(this).simpleUpload("/Admin/News/GetFiles", {
        start: function (file) {
            //upload started
            console.log("upload started");
        },
        progress: function (progress) {
            //received progress
            console.log("upload progress: " + Math.round(progress) + "%");
        },
        success: function (data) {
            //upload successful
            console.log("upload successful!");
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            //upload failed
            console.log("upload error: " + error.name + ": " + error.message);
        }
    });
});
```

when i upload file, it not enter controller .

when i put this code in view ( not use the script) and use that , enter in controller . whats the problem ?

```
 <input name="NewsFilePath" class="form-control NewsFilePathUpload" type="file">
```

Comment: You want to add input file upload HTML tag dynamically from javascript?and then it should go to the controller?

Comment: @MayankPatel yes . i want that

Comment: Please try out my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this.
By the click of your button call this method.

use jquery `.after` method

```
function adduploadfile() {
   $( ".insertfileuploads" ).after('<input name="NewsFilePath" class="form-control NewsFilePathUpload" type="file">');
}
```

This will put input tag after your elemet.

**EDIT:**
You need to bind change event after adding input element.

Working fiddle : [Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yzh14d9x/1/)

Comment: Your $('.NewsFilePathUpload').change(function () {}); method is not calling?

Comment: yea . it not call for go in controller

Comment: wait I am trying.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136159/discussion-between-kianoush-and-mayank-patel).

Comment: See my EDIT in answer.

Comment: now i am leaving office. Tell me if my answer helps you.